# GenericPrincipal vs ClaimsPrincipal. Difference in User property inside Razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, roles, claims

I have a project (MVC5 with SPA template) in which I need to copy functionality from another project. User.IsInRole() in Razor doesn't work.

Basically the roles are assign like this:

```
var currenIdentity = httpContext.User.Identity;
var roles = new List<string>();

roles.Add(Startup.AdministrationRole);
roles.Add(Startup.UserRole);

GenericPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(currenIdentity, roles.ToArray());
httpContext.User = principal;
```

In Razor I have

```
@if (User.IsInRole(Startup.AdministrationRole))
{
  @Html.ActionLink("Administrator »", "Config", "Admin", new { }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
}
```

In the original project when I debug, the  `User` property it's type is `System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal`

[image]

**But** when I debug the Razor View in my new project the `User` property is another type: `System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal`

[image]

I'm curious why there is a difference and therefore I can't check the roles directly from `System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal` ?

Comment: There is a module or a filter in your pipeline that does authentication and it sets the `ClaimsPrincipal` as the context's `User`. The information you provide is, unfortunately, not enough to help you. What you show how *roles are assigned* doesn't explain anything - you show a code without any context (e.g. does it run in a filter in your pipeline or it just runs once somewhere and is even not persisted across requests).

Comment: @WiktorZychla This code snippet with the roles is a part of a Filter that basically assigns a role depending on a claim that I recieve from Azure B2C token. This is the only filter that is attached to the pipeline. Also I skipped the conditions for simplicity.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Ahhh I got it  ... your comment was the key. It was the other way around of `... There is a filter in your pipeline that does authentication and it sets the ClaimsPrincipal as the context's User ...`. The Razor View is called from an `[AllowAnonymous]` controller, which overrides my filter, therefore the assignment of `GenericPrincipal` to the `User` is skipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GenericPrincipal` is assigned inside a custom filter. 
Problem was that the Razor View is called from an `[AllowAnonymous]` controller, which overrides my filter, therefore the assignment of `GenericPrincipal` to the User is skipped.